# Symfony Doctrine - Only display category item with objects assigned to it

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I've been trying to get my head around this but cannot seem to figure it out.

I am trying to only return the category items that has objects assigned to it.

As you can see below, the category has a collection of category items and then the category items has a collection of objects.

I am trying to return the category with the category items but only return the category items that has objects.

Category.php

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bundle\Entity\CategoryItem", mappedBy="category", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $filters;
```

CategoryItem.php

```
   /**
 * @var FilterCategory
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="filters")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bundle\Entity\Object", inversedBy="filters")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="filters_objects")
 */
private $hotels;
```

This is what I have so far in

CategoryRepository.php

```
public function findFiltersWithProducts()
{
    $parameters = array();
    $query  = $this->createQueryBuilder('category')
        ;
    $query->where('category.publish IS NULL');

    $query->innerJoin('category.filters', 'filters', 'WITH', *I THINK SOMETHING GOES HERE?*);

    $query->setParameters($parameters);
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

*EDIT*

Is there a way I can do:

```
    $query->innerJoin('category.filters', 'filters');
    /** Do a sub query on the above **/
     /** this is the subquery on the filter**/
    $query->andWhere(COUNT(filters.objects) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Replace

```
$query->innerJoin('category.filters', 'filters', 'WITH', *I THINK SOMETHING GOES HERE?*);
```

to

```
$query->innerJoin('category.filters', 'filters', 'category.filters.category_id = category.filters.id');
```

Comment: That didn't work, it still returns the full list of items